# ?cat=-1 Indexed Versions Of Homepage

Tags: categories, pagination, tax-query, rel-canonical

I'm finding some strange query strings on my homepage are indexed in Google and causing duplicate content. A couple of examples: https://sciencetrends.com/page/103/?cat=-1
https://sciencetrends.com/?cat=-3

I'm not sure how or why these pages are being created in Wordpress but it seems common for even large Wordpress sites: 
https://techcrunch.com/page/10/?cat=-1
https://blogs.wsj.com/law/page/10/?cat=-1
https://www.nytco.com/page/10/?cat=-1
http://www.bbcamerica.com/page/10/?cat=-1

Ideally, I'd like to remove all ?cat=* pages from the site and have then resolve to 404. Any thoughts on the best method to do so, .htaccess, Wordpress modification, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_GET['cat']) && $_GET['cat'] == -1) {
      header('Location: 404.php');
      exit;
```

Add this to your function.php file.

I also faced the same issue on my website. Every time I published a new article, the URL was not getting indexed in search engine and instead of URL, this unknown category shows up: `(?cat=-1)`